# How to make shortcut beginning of line ( ctrl-a ) work in kali linux?

Tags: bash

**Distribution**: SMP Debian 4.9.6-3kali2 (2017-01-30)

**Shell**: bash

**Program:** Terminal emulator

### Problem:

**Ctrl + a**   Go to the beginning of the line (Home) is doing a select all 
               instead .

**Ctrl + e**   Go to the End of the line (End) is working fine.

### **What I have tried:**

**stty** - change and print terminal line settings

**exemple:** stty intr "your_new_shortcut"

> $ stty -a
>
> > speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
> >
> > intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = ;
> >
> > eol2 = ; swtch = ; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt =^R;
> >
> > werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
> >
> > -parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
> >
> > -ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
> >
> > -iuclc -ixany imaxbel -iutf8
> >
> > opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
> >     isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
> >
> > echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc

### Solution

The only solution that I found, at this moment is to use the **Xfce terminal** include in my distro.

The **ctrl-a** beginning of the line works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found, at this moment is to use the Xfce terminal include in my distro.

The ctrl-a beginning of the line works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean, the terminal has the ability to move to the first character and end of line, so why wouldn't the rest of the distro be able to?

I have found a half solution with the text editor named Atom, this is just for source code management.  Perhaps if you're using a more advanced source code editor like RubyMine or any of the Jetbrains suites, they'll have a different way to configure them.

For Atom:

1. Press the hotkey `Ctrl-Comma`
2. Navigate to Keybindings
3. Find the built in link called `your keymap file` at the beginning of the file.

Copy and paste this into there:'atom-text-editor':

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-e': 'editor:move-to-end-of-screen-line'

'atom-workspace atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-a': 'editor:move-to-first-character-of-line'
  'ctrl-shift-a': 'core:select-all'
```

these controls will be more similar to MacOS.  Which I assume anyone asking this question will be making the switch over from there...